# How to access the Rep object in Avaya CMS scripting?

Tags: vbscript, avaya

I wanted to see if anyone knows how to access the Rep object in Avaya CMS scripting?

From what I gather it is an object, which stores a bunch of functions such as exportData, saveAsHTML, etc, but also contains the data that is to be exported.

I am trying to access it in the script so I can use a HTTP GET request to send the info to a node server.

There seems to be no documentation available for scripting in Avaya.

Does anyone know how I can effectively console.log() the object so I can read through it and figure out what I need from it?

Thanks,
Barry

EDIT: Just to mention, I am using Avaya CMS Supervisor R16.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Avaya and from what I can see it's quite vast. Which particular product are you using? Not managed to find a good reference documentation that refers to *"Avaya CMS Scripting"*, is that what it is known as?

Comment: Ah sorry, it is CMS Supervisor. You can create reports and you can automate them by scripting them. It's for managing agents and skills, among other things.